Graphdb preload with trig file resulting in error
I'm trying to preload a trig file which is around 24GB in terms of size.
Below is the command I am using.
docker run -v $(pwd)/graphdb-data:/opt/graphdb/home \
       -v $(pwd)/preload:/opt/graphdb-import \
       --entrypoint /opt/graphdb/dist/bin/importrdf \
       -e GDB_JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx12g -Xms2g" \
       -e graphdb.page.cache.size=512m \
       -e graphdb.workers.limit=2 \
       -e graphdb.query.evaluation.mode=disk \
       -e graphdb.repository.index.enable=false \
       -e graphdb.compression.enabled=true \
       -e graphdb.use.native.jena.model=true -e graphdb.verify-literals=false \
       ontotext/graphdb:10.7.1 \
       preload -s --force --recursive -q /tmp -c /opt/graphdb-import/graphdb-repo.ttl /opt/graphdb-import/backup.trig

Now, it seems to ingest the data however at the very end I get the following error:
12:05:31.663 [resolver] INFO  c.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload - 310,000,000 statements ...
12:06:30.853 [resolver] INFO  c.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload - 320,000,000 statements ...
12:06:50.697 [monitor file position] INFO  c.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload - File backup.trig processed to position 23,774,363,648 from 26,664,959,488 bytes
12:07:54.327 [resolver] INFO  c.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload - 330,000,000 statements ...
12:08:50.702 [monitor file position] INFO  c.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload - File backup.trig processed to position 25,267,535,872 from 26,664,959,488 bytes
12:09:28.692 [resolver] INFO  c.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload - 340,000,000 statements ...
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.base.AbstractLiteral$NumberLiteral.parseDouble(AbstractLiteral.java:367)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.base.AbstractLiteral.value(AbstractLiteral.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.base.AbstractLiteral.doubleValue(AbstractLiteral.java:141)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload.processLiteral(Preload.java:2124)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Resolver.write(Resolver.java:61)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Resolver.createid(Resolver.java:124)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Resolver.run(Resolver.java:203)
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2056)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2090)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload$LocalHandler.handleStatement(Preload.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.trig.TriGParser.reportStatement(TriGParser.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseObject(TurtleParser.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseObjectList(TurtleParser.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parsePredicateObjectList(TurtleParser.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.trig.TriGParser.parseTriples(TriGParser.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.trig.TriGParser.parseGraph(TriGParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.trig.TriGParser.parseStatement(TriGParser.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.loadInputStreamOrReader(RDFLoader.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.load(RDFLoader.java:249)
    at com.ontotext.load.GraphdbRDFLoader.load(GraphdbRDFLoader.java:89)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload.processSingleFileInternal(Preload.java:2103)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload.lambda$processSingleFile$22(Preload.java:2053)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
12:10:32.001 [sorting] INFO  c.ontotext.graphdb.importrdf.Preload - Sorter thread finished.

This file is a direct backup of a dev instance. I'm looking for a way to ignore the errors/inference of types. Is it possible to ignore such errors or simply ingest the correct data only with preload command within graphdb?

did you check the literal at the given position? Maybe the export wrote some ill-formed data? I'd check with Jena riot CLI tool or something first. Other than that, I"m not aware of such an "ignore" option, maybe it exists but hard to find in the docs.

in the Workbench docs there would be such an option to ignore non-fatal errors: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.7/loading-data-using-the-workbench.html - the question would be what they consider as "fatal"

You can try to load the data removing the -s option and adding -p. More about those options
 -p,--partialLoad              allow partial load of file that contains corrupt line

 -s,--stopOnFirstError         stop process if the dataset contains a corrupt file


From the documentation this only seems to be valid for the load option but not the preload option

You are right, we took another look at the issue and it seems that the preload currently cannot continue the load after that scenario. I've opened a bug in our project to catch such errors and continue the load. As an alternative you could use the load option.

Thank you Konstantin
